# Mysteriously missing PNG resource in IOS app

Tags: ios, uiimage

I recently added an image (png file) as a resource to my app.  I am loading the image with:

UIImage* img = [UIImage imagedNamed: @"name.png"];

When I run the app in the IOS simulator, it loads the image correctly.  I've tried the iPad, iPad Retina, and iPad Retina 64 bit simulators - they all load it correctly.  But when I run the app on my iPad Air, the call to UIImage.imageNamed returns null.

Is there something I'm missing about how I need to add the image to the project?  I would have thought that if there was an issue, it should also be showing up when I run in the simulator.

Thanks.

- Dave

Comment: don't use ".png" in the name. Also do you have x2 (retina) version of the image?

Comment: Have you checked that the image has been added to the project target? Select the image and select your project under 'Target membership' in inspector.

Comment: Are you sure the image is included in the application target?  Xcode doesn't remove resources that are no longer included, so have you tried deleting the application from the simulator and rerunning it?  The simulator (probably, it depends on your OSX file system) isn't case-sensitive, but the live device is.

Comment: Check the case of the filename - the simulator doesn't care (as its running on OS X), a proper device does.

Comment: Thanks Rich - you were right.  I actually didn't see your comment until I added my own answer below.  I'm not getting notified on posts to my threads for some reason, I didn't realize anyone had responded.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I figured out the problem.  Apparently, resource names are case sensitive on the device, but not in the simulator.  Fixing the string name of the resource to have the same case as the actual file name fixed the problem.